# How to compare the nodes and edges in two graphs?

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I've got graphs of Berlin on January 1, 2020 and January 1, 2021, but how do I compare the changes of edges and nodes in the two maps?

```
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations
from IPython.display import clear_output
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from IPython.display import Image
```

Getting the network of Berlin in 2021-01-01.

```
ox.utils.config(overpass_settings='[out:json][timeout:180][date:"2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"]')

G_21=ox.graph.graph_from_place('Berlin,Germany', network_type='all_private', simplify=True, retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=False,which_result=None, buffer_dist=None, clean_periphery=True,custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway|path|living_street"]["bicycle"!~"no"]')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G_21,node_size=1,edge_linewidth=0.5)
```

Getting the network of Berlin in 2020-01-01

```
ox.utils.config(overpass_settings='[out:json][timeout:180][date:"2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"]')

G_20=ox.graph.graph_from_place('Berlin,Germany', network_type='all_private', simplify=True, retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=False,which_result=None, buffer_dist=None, clean_periphery=True,custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway|path|living_street"]["bicycle"!~"no"]')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G_20,node_size=1,edge_linewidth=0.5)
```

Now I wonder how to identify the changes of nodes and edges, then mark the added ones in G_21 and deleted ones in G_20.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that [OSMnx](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/) just uses NetworkX graph objects, so you can treat your two resulting graphs the same way you would any NetworkX graph, including handling their nodes/edges with set logic:

```py
import osmnx as ox
place = 'Berlin, Germany'
cf = '["highway"~"cycleway|path|living_street"]["bicycle"!~"no"]'
settings = '[out:json][timeout:180][date:"{year}-01-01T00:00:00Z"]'

# get the 2021 graph
ox.utils.config(overpass_settings=settings.format(year=2021))
G_21 = ox.graph.graph_from_place(place, custom_filter=cf, retain_all=True)

# get the 2020 graph
ox.utils.config(overpass_settings=settings.format(year=2020))
G_20 = ox.graph.graph_from_place(place, custom_filter=cf, retain_all=True)

# identify the nodes/edges that were deleted/added
nodes_del = G_20.nodes - G_21.nodes
nodes_add = G_21.nodes - G_20.nodes
edges_del = G_20.edges - G_21.edges
edges_add = G_21.edges - G_20.edges
```

Beyond identifying which nodes/edges were deleted/added, you may also be interested in the changes to their attribute values, in which case you can just inspect the attribute dicts of your nodes/edges and see which key/value combos changed.